# Please let me know what wrong i am doing in this python code?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

Loop through the list of people who should take the poll. If they have already taken the poll, print out a message thanking them for responding. If they have not yet taken the poll, print out a message inviting them to take a poll.

```
favorite_language = {
    "jen": "python",
    "sarah": "c",
    "edward":"ruby",
    "phil":"python"}

take_poll = ["sarah", "arjun", "phil"]

for name  in favorite_language.keys():
    print(f"Thank you for voting, {name}.")

    if name in take_poll:
        to_poll = favorite_language[name].title()
        print(f"Please take part in poll, {to_poll}.")
```

Comment: what is the error showing?

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this will fulfill your requirements, if it not then please inform me. Thanks

```
favorite_language = {
    "jen": "python",
    "sarah": "c",
    "edward":"ruby",
    "phil":"python"}

take_poll = ["sarah", "arjun", "phil"]

for name  in favorite_language.keys():
    if name in take_poll:
        print(f"Thank you for voting, {name}.")

    else:
        to_poll = favorite_language[name].title()
        print(f"Please take part in poll, {to_poll}.")
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you want. Two names are in both lists so I'm giving the `favorite_language` list priority. I assume `favorite_language` is for persons who have already voted.

```
favorite_language = {
    "jen": "python",
    "sarah": "c",
    "edward":"ruby",
    "phil":"python"}

take_poll = ["sarah", "arjun", "phil"]

for name in set(favorite_language.keys())|set(take_poll):
    if name in favorite_language:
        print(f"Thank you for voting, {name.title()}.")
    else:
        to_poll = name.title()
        print(f"Please take part in poll, {to_poll}.")
```

Output

```
Please take part in poll, Arjun.
Thank you for voting, Edward.
Thank you for voting, Phil.
Thank you for voting, Sarah.
Thank you for voting, Jen.
```